# Exam class: Sectioning command spacing when used within questions environment

Tags: spacing, exam

I have the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}

% \renewcommand{\questionshook}{
%     \setlength{\itemsep}{30pt}
% }


\begin{document}
\section{leet}
someleet. 
\section{moreleet}
somemoreleet.
\begin{questions}
    \question something here.
    \begin{EnvFullwidth}
        \section{blah}
    \end{EnvFullwidth}
    \question blahblah.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this code returns the following results, with the `\renewcommand` block commented on the left, and uncommented on the right (open the images in new tabs, ideally):

[image]
[image]

Notice two things:

1. The spacing *above* the `blah` section is *equal* in both cases, but clearly *more* than the normal sectioning space.
2. The spacing *below* the same section is massively expanded when the question spacing is changed.

Another thing I noted, is that commands such as `\clearpage` or `\newpage` do nothing to eliminate the space above the sectioning command, when placed in a `questions` environment.

My goal is as such, for the sectioning commands **within the `questions` environment** (i.e. not just `\section`, but `\subsection`, etc too):

1. The spacing *above* the sectioning command should be *equal* to the `\itemsep{}` set in the `\newcommand`.
2. The spacing *below* the sectioning command should be *equal* to the usual spacing below a sectioning command *not* within the `questions` environment.
3. If a sectioning command begins on a new page, or `\clearpage`/`\newpage` is explicitly specified, then there should be *no additional space* above the sectioning text, i.e. a new page nullifies the space mentioned in 1.

Can this be achieved with some wrangling?